# Hadoop namenode cannot find datanode

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, virtual-machine

Environment:`2 Ubuntu 14.04 VMs` running under VMware workstation.

I have successfully set up a single node cluster and I am now trying to setup a fully-distributed one with one namenode running on master and one datanode running on slave.

After running start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh, I can see all needed processes on both master and slave machines.(namenode,resourcemanager,secondarynamenode on master and datanode, nodemanager on slave.

However I cannot find my datanode on master:50070 (namenode webapp).
`telnet master 9000` from slave replies with successful connection.

I have been stuck by this whole day.

Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: check the datanode's log. It should explain why it is not working. Have you put master on the `conf/slaves` file, too?

Comment: @vefthym The log says my datanode got problem connecting to the master node on the port 9000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add a property in mapred-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>master:9001</value>
</property>
```

let me it works or not.